# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'user'

Tags: python, django

Am new to django and i created a model and a signal, on change of a field, it should triger the signal and create a new record in another model with the user_id, but its giving me this error... When i change the status to approved the signal is suppose to create a new object in he ApprovedArticle object but it's showing an error, i don't know what i did wrong
**Model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from article.models import Article
from adminactivities.models import User, ApprovedArticleStatus
from django.utils import timezone

DEFAULT_STATUS = 2


class ApprovedArticle(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET('Unknown'))
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    views = models.CharField(max_length=150, default=0)
    link_views = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='NIL')
    approved_status = models.ForeignKey(ApprovedArticleStatus, on_delete=models.SET('Uncategorized'),
                                        default=DEFAULT_STATUS)
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    added_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.article.title

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ApprovedArticle, self).__init__(*args, *kwargs)
        self.original_views = self.views

DEFAULT_STATUS = 1
class Article( models.Model ):
    title = models.CharField( max_length = 250 )
    category = models.ForeignKey( ArticleCategory, on_delete = models.SET( "Uncategorized" ) )
    status = models.ForeignKey( ArticleStatus, on_delete = models.SET( "Pending" ), default = DEFAULT_STATUS )
    user = models.ForeignKey( settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete = models.SET( "Unknown" ) )
    document = models.FileField( upload_to = 'documents/', null = False )
    cover_pic = models.ImageField( default = 'cover.jpg', upload_to = 'cover_pics/' )
    date_added = models.DateTimeField( default = timezone.now )
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __str__( self ):
        return self.title

    def save( self, **kwargs ):
        super().save()
        img = Image.open( self.cover_pic.path )
        if img.height > 768 or img.width > 1280:
            output_size = (1280, 768)
            img.thumbnail( output_size )
            img.save( self.cover_pic.path )
```

**Signal.py**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender = Article)
    def add_approved_article(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        if kwargs['created']:
            print('Article Created... Perform NO action')
        else:
            if str(instance.status) == "Approved":
                if ApprovedArticle.objects.filter(article_id = instance.pk):
                    print("Already Exist")
                else:
                    approved = ApprovedArticle.objects.create(user = instance.user, user_id = instance.user_id,
                                                              article = instance, article_id = instance.pk)
                    approved.save()

            else:
                print("Not Approved")
```

**Views.py**

```
class PendingArticleDetailView( SuccessMessageMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView ):
model = Article
template_name = 'adminarticle/article_detail.html'
form_class = ArticleStatusForm
success_message = "Article Updated Successfully"
login_url = 'login-view'

def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_adminuser != True:
        return redirect( 'error-404' )
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

def get_success_url( self ):
    return reverse( 'view-admin-article', kwargs = { 'pk': self.object.id } )

def get_context_data( self, **kwargs ):
    context = super( PendingArticleDetailView, self ).get_context_data( **kwargs )
    context[ 'form' ] = ArticleStatusForm( instance = self.get_object() )
    context[ 'pending_article' ] = Article.objects.filter( user = self.object.user.id, status = 1 ).count()
    context[ 'approved_article' ] = Article.objects.filter( user = self.object.user.id, status = 2 ).count()
    context[ 'declined_article' ] = Article.objects.filter( user = self.object.user.id, status = 3 ).count()

    return context

def post( self, request, *args, **kwargs ):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    form = self.get_form()
    if form.is_valid():
        return self.form_valid( form )
    else:
        return self.form_invalid( form )

def form_valid( self, form ):
    form.save()
    return super( PendingArticleDetailView, self ).form_valid( form )
```

**Complete Error Trace**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/article/article/1/change/

Django Version: 2.1.2
Python Version: 3.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django_cleanup',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'password_reset.apps.Password_resetConfig',
 'mywriteup.apps.MywriteupConfig',
 'myauth.apps.MyauthConfig',
 'adminactivities.apps.AdminactivitiesConfig',
 'account.apps.AccountConfig',
 'article.apps.ArticleConfig',
 'wallet.apps.WalletConfig',
 'myadmins.apps.MyadminsConfig',
 'adminarticle.apps.AdminarticleConfig',
 'admintransaction.apps.AdmintransactionConfig',
 'adminusers.apps.AdminusersConfig',
 'adminupdates.apps.AdminupdatesConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
  604.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in change_view
  1639.         return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changeform_view
  1525.             return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in _changeform_view
  1564.                 self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in save_model
  1091.         obj.save()

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\Documents\Projects\django\my_writeup\article\models.py" in save
  23.         super().save()

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  718.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  758.                 update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py" in send
  175.             for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py" in <listcomp>
  175.             for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\Documents\Projects\django\my_writeup\article\signals\handlers.py" in add_approved_article
  25.                                                           article = instance, article_id = instance.pk)

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in create
  413.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  718.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  748.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  831.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
  869.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
  1136.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1288.             for sql, params in self.as_sql():

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in as_sql
  1241.                 for obj in self.query.objs

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in <listcomp>
  1241.                 for obj in self.query.objs

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in <listcomp>
  1240.                 [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in prepare_value
  1182.             value = field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=self.connection)

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_db_prep_save
  790.         return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_db_prep_value
  956.             value = self.get_prep_value(value)

File "C:\Users\DENIS JOHN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  965.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/article/article/1/change/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'user'
```

Comment: I have just edited my question and added the error trace

Comment: downvote removed

Answer (score 0):

It might be the use of `on_delete = models.SET( "Unknown" )` on the line

```
user = models.ForeignKey( settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete = models.SET( "Unknown" ) )
```

Setting `user` to the string `"Unknown"` instead of `None` would cause a conversion error.

Comment: I changed it to on_delete=models.SET(None) but still giving the same error, i even deleted all my old migration files and db but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I saw where my problem was coming from but I don't know why. the problem was from my model.py **init** method. I removed the **init** method and everything worked perfectly.
**Model.py**

```
class ApprovedArticle(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET('Unknown'))
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    views = models.CharField(max_length=150, default=0)
    link_views = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='NIL')
    approved_status = models.ForeignKey(ApprovedArticleStatus, on_delete=models.SET('Uncategorized'),
                                        default=DEFAULT_STATUS)
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    added_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.article.title

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ApprovedArticle, self).__init__(*args, *kwargs)
        self.original_views = self.views
```